# Will Internet provider know what sub-page I visited on a site?

Tags: internet, web, confidentiality

Let's say in my address bar I see such link:
[Privatebin URL/key interception?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244530/privatebin-url-key-interception)

Can somebody besides server and me know that I'm visiting not just `security.stackexchangec.com` but excactly `../questions/244530/privatebin-url-key-interception` ?

Comment: Assuming you're using `https`, then no. I'll write up a full answer shortly.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth we have a bunch of questions much like this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7705/does-ssl-tls-https-hide-the-urls-being-accessed